# HTML Submenu disappearing when trying to hover over it

Tags: html, css

i created an HTML menu that has a submenu, however when i hover over the main menu and it shows the submenu, i cant get access to it. It disappears before i can move my mouse down to navigate to it. I dont know what i am doing wrong, maybe with my code someone can help out. thanks

```
#header ul { position: absolute; top: 88px; left: 0; }
#header ul li { display: inline;}
#header ul li a { font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; margin-right: 20px; color: #fff; line-height: 2em;}
#header ul li ul{ position: static;display: none; z-index: 999;top:150%;}
#header ul li:hover a { font-weight:bold; color: #000000}
#header ul li:hover ul { display: block; position:absolute;}
```

**Edited to show HTML**

```
     <ul>
                <li><a href="/Default.aspx">Home</a>              
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Cover/HRMS.aspx">HRMS</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a href="/Cover/HRMS.aspx">Position</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="/Cover/HRMS.aspx">COA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="/Cover/HRMS.aspx">Employee</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="/Cover/HRMS.aspx">Estate</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Cover/EmployeeMaintenance.aspx">Employee Maintenance</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="/Cover/Payroll.aspx">Payroll</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="/Cover/DataTransfer.aspx">Data Transfer</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="/Cover/Reports.aspx">Reports</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="/Cover/Administration.aspx">Administration</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="/Cover/Help.aspx">Help</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: i added it to the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific; could you edit that down to only the *relevant*/[sscce](http://sscce.org) HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a disconnect between the main  and the children `<ul>`.

In your style `ul li ul { position: static;display: none; z-index: 999;top:150%;}`

The `top:150%;` creates the disconnect (so you hover over nothing instead of hitting the submenu's  `:hover` logic when you hover from `ul li` to `ul li ul`). You can try using `padding-top` instead:

`ul li ul{ position: static;display: none; z-index: 999; padding-top:10px;}`

Edit: [Here](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-dropdown-menu/) is a working nav menu example you can look at.

Edit 2:  Looks like it works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE.

Comment: tried that and its sending the submenue  down the page and i still cannot get to scroll over it. :/

Comment: hey, im trying something different..trying to get the submenu in the same line using :: #header ul li:hover ul { display: inline; position:static;} .. but it changes too fast.. any way to rectify this?

Comment: Can you post a block of your updated CSS in the question?

I am using this  `#header ul li:hover ul {display: block ;position:absolute;}`

Answer (score 0):

You will need a direct child selector, somewhere along the line of:

`li:hover > ul { display: block; (...) }`

This means that the child `<ul>` in the list will be displayed when it's direct parent `<li>` has been hovered upon.

Comment: hey, im trying something different..trying to get the submenu in the same line using :: #header ul li:hover ul { display: inline; position:static;} .. but it changes too fast.. any way to rectify this?

Comment: Use the direct child select `>`, like `#header ul li:hover > ul { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one article about Dropdown menu in Portuguese, but I guess it will help you with google translate or something like that.

Check it out: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3474/menu-em-css-menu-dropdown-horizontal-com-html5-e-css3.aspx